# Padding values when converting to larger types in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, posix

case 1:

```
int8_t a = -10;
int32_t b;
b = (int32_t)a;
```

case 2:

```
uint8_t a = 10;
uint32_t b;
b = (uint32_t)a;
```

What will b be in these two cases? Is there any guarantees? Will the 3 extra bytes during the type conversion be padded with 0?

Clarification: larger as in more bytes.

Comment: it is guaranteed by the standard that the conversion to a larger compatible type does not alter the value. So b is -10 in case 1 and 10 in case 2.

Comment: @mch Would b be -10 in case 1? That's very interesting. That would mean it doesn't just pad 0s, but it actually shifts the signed/complement number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting between integer types is guaranteed to be "correct". That is, if the value being converted (regardless of its type) is representable in the converted-to type, the result will be that same value.

In the first case, -10 is representable as an `int32_t`, so `b` will end up holding the 32-bit representation of -10. On 2's complement machines (virtually all modern computers), that'll have a whole lot of 1's at the top. On x86, the `cbw`, `cwd`, `cwde`, and `cdq` instructions are used to do this.

In the second case, 10 is representable as a `uint32_t`, so `b` will end up holding the 32-bit representation of 10. That'll have a whole lot of zeros at the top.

You can think of this as "sign-extension" -- when widening signed integers, the extra bits are copied from the MSB of the source operand -- but that's just implementation details. The rule is, if it can be represented in the destination type, it's represented correctly in the destination type.

The one extra guarantee that C/C++ gives you, is that when *narrowing* unsigned types -- converting from a bigger unsigned integer to a smaller unsigned integer -- the result will be the same as chopping off the upper bits, regardless of whether the value is representable in the smaller type. For signed integers, all bets are off (but in practice, the same thing always happens, and sometimes that means a positive value becomes negative).

Comment: Re-signed ints: the "same thing" will happen UNLESS the C compiler decides to delete your code. Which some will do if it can be justified mathematically by assuming signed integers are unbounded.

Comment: @user3710044 Are you aware of any situation in which this would actually happen? I can't think what the compiler would gain by assuming such things, in any but the most contrived of circumstances.

Comment: I don't think it's likely to gain much either, but they do it anyway, it's a well known problem with current compilers: Google for "fno-strict-overflow" starting, say, [here](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120)